# What is the proper name for "class versioning"

Tags: design-patterns

I am looking to name the problem I am trying to solve so I can look at others' solutions. It feels like a common problem (indeed, [How to implement "class versioning" (using different version of the same class)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/449569/309334) asks about a similar issue). However, the search terms I have been using ("class versioning", "object versioning", "persistent object version" and several others) have not yielded good results.

*Note that this question is not about how to solve the issue. If I can't find anything, I'll ask that question later. This question is asking for the name of the problem (or a pattern that solves the problem).*

I write software to support a large community of scientists in active research. It archives, analyzes and publishes their results so that they can better collaborate. Because of the active nature of the field, the models of the basic objects are in constant evolution -- as new discoveries are made, the old models no longer fit. This means that next year my objects may have new fields, may lose fields, and some extant fields may gain or lose constraints. However, it is also a requirement to archive the results of this year and not change them so that future scientists can understand the papers that were published this year using that data.

Thus the problem has three parts:

1. Our domain model will change - but we can't predict how in advance
2. Old objects need to be stored unmodified. New objects should take advantage of the new knowledge.
3. There are many similarities between the old and new objects. We would like to take advantage of these. For example, if someone discovers that flowers have UV-signatures, so we start including that in our flower model, we'd still like to be able to count the petals in any flower whether or not we know their UV-signature.

The problem bears some similarity to requirements drift except that here it is a fixed requirement that the software deal with changing models of the world and that the "drift" is happening during maintenance and that the "drift" is something to be welcomed rather than avoided because it represents the advancement of our knowledge - the *raison d'être* for the software.

Comment: The correct term is "versioning" or "versioned".  but that's really how it applies to the data, not the class.  If you serialize a class to a byte stream that byte stream is now independent of an instance of the class that sourced it.  You could "version" the class or "version" the serialization code.  Things like Data Transfer Objects, and protocol buffers are good things to look at when decoupling your domain classes from data at rest or data in transit.

Comment: I think you're talking about http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_evolution

Comment: @PeterRitchie "Versioning" is a very general term. It applies to changes in source code. Or when objects retain a history throughout their lifetime. I am looking for what to call the requirement that the software adapt to a shifting world model while maintaining backward compatibility. You are right that DTO etc and including versions are potential approaches to solving the problem. I want to know what to call the problem itself.

Comment: There isn't a pattern for this and there isn't a single term for all-encompassing backward compatibility.  Although, Semantic Versioning (http://semver.org/) helps to focus certain non-functional requirements from one application version to another (major, minor, patch, build...)

Comment: @Leo it is software evolution, but it is software _designed_ to evolve in a specific way - responding to changes in a domain model represented by a subset of its objects.

Comment: well, I agree with @PeterRitchie. I don't know any specific term for this kind of software resiliency for model changes.